# Inserting label before input fields

Tags: javascript

Been trying to find some help online but no luck.

I have made a button that dynamically inserts input fields but I cant seem to get a label next to each one. I'm sure its a small fix but my brain isn't working today.

```
<script text="javascript"> 
    var i = 0;

    function increment() {
      i += 1;
    }
    function addeducationfields() {
      var r = document.createElement('div');
      //Inputs
      var ie = document.createElement("INPUT");
      var n = document.createElement("INPUT");
      var l = document.createElement("INPUT");
      var s = document.createElement("INPUT");
      //Labels
      var x = document.createElement("LABEL");
      var t = document.createTextNode("Iestādes Nosaukums:");
      var o = document.createElement("LABEL");
      var p = document.createTextNode("Gads no - līdz:");
      var q = document.createElement("LABEL");
      var w = document.createTextNode("Specialitāte");
      //Breaks
      var b = document.createElement("br")
      var b1 = document.createElement("br")
      var b2 = document.createElement("br")
      var b3 = document.createElement("br")

      ie.setAttribute("class", "Edinput1");
      ie.setAttribute("type", "text");
      ie.setAttribute("placeholder", "Iestādes nosaukums");
      n.setAttribute("class", "Edinput2");
      n.setAttribute("type", "text");
      n.setAttribute("placeholder", "No");
      l.setAttribute("class", "Edinput3");
      l.setAttribute("type", "text");
      l.setAttribute("placeholder", "Līdz");    
      s.setAttribute("class", "Edinput4");
      s.setAttribute("type", "text");
      s.setAttribute("placeholder", "Specialitāte");   

      x.setAttribute("for", "Edinput1");
      x.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("Education").insertBefore(x,document.getElementById("Edinput1"));

      increment();

      ie.setAttribute("name", "EdName[ " + i + " ][0]"); //Keep attribute in lower case
      r.appendChild(ie);
      r.appendChild(b);

      n.setAttribute("name", "Year1[ " + i + "][1]");
      r.appendChild(n); 

      l.setAttribute("name", "Year2[ " + i + " ][2]"); 
      r.appendChild(l);
      r.appendChild(b2);

      s.setAttribute("name", "Specialitate[ " + i + "][3]");
      r.appendChild(s);
      r.appendChild(b3);


      document.getElementById("Education").appendChild(r);   

}
</script>
```

Needed to add more text because it sayed I had too much code. 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789

Comment: Yikes. You're much better off storing that information in an object and then iterating over it to produce the elements than doing it long-hand like that.

Comment: I can see a view like https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xdubmg?file=index.js .What is the expected view

Comment: The view need to be that the label is on the left side of the input field. I have a CSS file that puts the labels and input fields correctly. i just need to find a way to put a label after each input field. Hope u know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the input in the label tag. Here I've also used a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) to attach the elements before adding them to the DOM.

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

const label = document.createElement('LABEL');
const labelText = document.createTextNode('Iestādes Nosaukums');
const input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
label.appendChild(labelText);
label.appendChild(input);

frag.appendChild(label);

document.body.appendChild(frag)
```

The label is to the left of the corresponding input.

Here was the suggestion I mentioned in the comments. It uses an object to store the element data which you can iterate over (I used [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but a simple for/loop would be ok) to produce the HTML that you can then attach to the page.

```js
const data = [{
    label: 'Iestādes Nosaukums',
    placeholder: 'Iestādes nosaukums',
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    label: 'Gads no - līdz',
    placeholder: 'No',
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    label: 'Specialitāte',
    placeholder: 'Specialitāte',
    type: 'text'
  }
];

const html = data.map(input => {
  return (
    `<label for="${input.label}">${input.label}
    <input id="${input.label}" class="edit" placeholder="${input.placeholder}" type="${input.type}" />
    </label>`
  );
}).join('');

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

Note that in this example I also included the `for` and `id` attributes [to aid with accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: With this it refreshes the page and opens a window with just this scripts details. I need to be able to add these fields on the same page and add unlimited amount. Also this is my first time coding in javascript.